# 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'tick'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to use Pygame's Clock.tick, but it's not there. I'm positive Pygame has it for Python 3, even if I use `dir(pygame.time.Clock)`, it's still not there. I'm not sure if I'm doing something drastically wrong or Pygame doesn't have it for Python 3.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *

class Pong_Ball(object):
    def __init__(self, screen, screen_height, screen_width):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_height = screen_height
        self.screen_width = screen_width

    def update(self):
        #pong ball's properties
        self.ball_color = 191,191,191
        self.pos_x = 100
        self.pos_y = 100
        self.vel_x = 1
        self.vel_y = 1

        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            #clear the screen
            self.screen.fill((0,50,100))

            #move the pong ball
            self.pos_x += self.vel_x
            self.pos_y += self.vel_y

            #keep the ball on the screen
            if self.pos_x > self.screen_width or self.pos_x < 0:
                self.vel_x = -self.vel_x
            if self.pos_y > self.screen_height or self.pos_y < 0:
                self.vel_y = -self.vel_y

            #draw the pong ball
            self.position = self.pos_x, self.pos_y
            pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, self.ball_color, self.position, 10)

            #update the display
            pygame.time.Clock.tick(60)
            pygame.display.update()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
    ball = Pong_Ball(screen, 600, 800)
    ball.update()

main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah.  The [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock), though perfectly standard, could be a little confusing.  Even though they write `Clock.tick`, they don't mean that it's a staticmethod of the class.  You call it on an instance:

```
>>> import pygame
>>> clock = pygame.time.Clock()
>>> clock
<Clock(fps=0.00)>
>>> clock.tick
<built-in method tick of Clock object at 0xb402b408>
>>> clock.tick()
14487
>>> clock.tick()
836
```

To confirm that it's behaving:

```
>>> import time
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print clock.tick()
...     time.sleep(0.17)
...     
22713
172
171
171
172
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `pygame.time.Clock.tick(60)` with `pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)`.